The limit of $\frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2) \ldots (1+a^n)}$ $a>0$
I was given the following question in a homework assignment:
Given $a>0$ either both statements are true, both false, or one is true, and the other false (any combination):
1)
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2) \ldots (1+a^n)} = 1$
2)
$\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2) \ldots (1+a^n)} = a$
My solution to disprove (1):
I constructed a sequence:
$b_n = \frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2) \ldots (1+a^n)}$.
Since $b_n >0$ for all $n$ I was able to use the test: $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = a \cdot \bigg( \frac{1}{1+a^{n+1}}\bigg)$.
If $0<a<1$, then the limit of the ratio is less than 1, and $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n =0$. If $a \ge 1$ then the limit of the ration goes to 0 (zero).
In any case, for $0<a<1$ $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n \ne 1$.
As for (2) I suppose the same logic would apply, but I am not very sure...
I would greatly appreciate either a reassurance for my solution, or a tip in the right direction, if my solution, to any of the sections, is incorrect.
Thank you very much in advance!

Your derivation is good but $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=0$ is not correct since $a\bigg( \frac{1}{1+a^{n+1}}\bigg)=a$ for $a\in(0,1)$.

@MathArt You have computed the limit of $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ not of $b_n$.

Thanks for kind reminding. Yes, I missed that.

The ratio test is effective as ${b_{n+1}\over b_n}$ tends to $0$ for $a>1,$ to ${1\over 2}$ if $a=1$ and to $a$ if $0<a<1.$ In all cases the limit of the ratio is less than $1.$ Hence $b_n\to 0.$

Instead of applying the ratio test the squeeze theorem can be used. Namely
$$0\le b_n\le \begin{cases} \left ({a\over 1+a}\right )^n & a\ge 1\\
a^n & 0<a<1\end{cases}$$
Thus $b_n\to 0.$

Note that
$$
b_n=\frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2) \ldots (1+a^n)}=\frac{a}{a+1}\cdot\frac{a}{a^2+1}\cdot
...\cdot \frac{a}{a^n+1}
$$
If $a\ge 1$ then each term $\le x:=\frac a{a+1}<1$ and thus $b_n \le x^{n}$. On the other hand, if $a<1$, then $b_n\le a^n$. In both cases $b_n\to 0$.

If $a>1$ then ${a\over a+1}>{1\over 2}.$

Thanks, corrected.

You are right except for the case $a=1$. If $a=1$, then the ratio doesn't go to $0$. The ratio is $\frac{a}{2} <1$. Thus $b_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.
Or $a=1$ could have also been dealt with like: if $a=1$, then $b_n=\frac{1}{2^n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

We have for $a= 1$ the sequence is equal to $\frac1{2^n} \to 0$ and for $a\neq 1$
$$\frac{a^n}{(1+a)(1+a^2) \ldots (1+a^n)}\le \frac{a^n}{1+a^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}\to0$$

I think you may skip $a^n$ in the last denominator.

@RyszardSzwarc You are completely right! Thanks I fix it
